# ASP.NET Core API Composition patttern

Tags: asp.net-core, rest, микросервисы

Никак не могу найти пример агрегации данных из нескольких микросервисов с пагинацией данных.

Пример - есть сервис продуктов и сервис описания продуктов.
Нужен запрос, который отобразит продуктамы с их описаниями.

```
api/products?limit=10&skip=0
api/productDescriptions?limit=10&skip=0

class Product{
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public string Description {get;set;} // fill from api/productDescriptions
}
```

Каким образом построить API, чтобы можно было на лету агрегировать данные.
Вариант с запросом `api/productDescriptions?id=1` я не хочу рассматривать, так как это вызов сервисов в цикле.

Думаю об `api/productDescriptions?ids=1,2,3`, тогда можно одним запросом получить все данные. Но в ответах на SO многие говорили что это bad idea.

Так каким образом это делается?

Comment: непонятно, зачем нужен отдельный сервис описания продуктов? Но вообще у вас не особо чтобы был какой то выбор, кроме как `api/productDescriptions?ids=1,2,3`